# Format time (seconds) relative to amount in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, time, format, seconds

I'm trying to output a dynamic figure in seconds to: seconds, minutes, hours or days depending on the total.

What would be the best way to quickly format the seconds such as below?

```
33 seconds = 33 seconds
92 seconds = 1.5 minutes
6200 seconds = 1.7 hours
180000 seconds = 2 days
980010 seconds = 1.6 weeks
```

I was hoping there was a jQuery library that could handle this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Juhana - It looks about right, Couldn't  find that from an inital google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function below works quite well. You can add some conditional statements within the function to return the exact string you want. i.e just the seconds if all the other values are `==0` etc.

```
function convertFromSeconds(seconds)
{

var numdays = Math.floor(seconds / 86400);
var numhours = Math.floor((seconds % 86400) / 3600);
var numminutes = Math.floor(((seconds % 86400) % 3600) / 60);
var numseconds = ((seconds % 86400) % 3600) % 60;

return numdays + " days " + numhours + " hours " + numminutes + " minutes " + numseconds + " seconds";

}
```